# Select element not working in jquery-ui dlalog title (Firefox)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-dialog

**Setup**

I use jquery-ui to create a dialog and set the title for said dialog which contains a <select>-element.

```
$(".dialog").dialog()
$(".dialog").dialog("option", "draggable", false)    
$(".dialog").dialog("option", "title", "<select><option>option 1</option><option>option 2</option></select>")
```

**Problem (firefox only / [tested with Firefox 17/16 on Win7/OpenSuse 12.2) )**

The dialog title bar contains the select-element which i cannot use by left clicking it. It will open if right click it or select it using shortcuts but a left click wont do it.

Example given via Jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/cma4X/2/ )

Any Ideas how to fix it or at least what the problem is?

Comment: What version of Firefox on what platform? Seems to work on an old 3.6 version I have for testing on latest OS X.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if jQuery disables any input in the titlebar but you can circumvent this by adding your select element after the dialog is drawn and positioning it with CSS back in the title.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cma4X/8/)**

```
$(".dialog").dialog({
    draggable: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').after('<select style="position:absolute;top:12px;left:25px;"><option>option 1</option><option>option 2</option></select>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that maybe a solution to the problem. Any Ideas why this happens? It used to work with older versions of firefox

Comment: I'd have to dig through the guts of the element on github.